# Migrate the existing webview data to crosswalk

Tags: cordova, crosswalk

I am updating an app to use Crosswalk (version 19 - to support android 4.0, sdk version 14). But Crosswalk does not seem to be able to read the existing data from localStorage or websql. **Is there a way (perhaps a config setting?) to migrate the existing webview data to crosswalk?**